# Google Maps IOS SDK didLongPressAtCoordinate

Tags: ios, google-maps

i am using Google Maps in my iOS-App.
Currently everything is working after Google updated their library for iOS7 it is even working better but i got a problem i can not determine if this is a problem due to my code or Google did not implemented it right.

All my Delegate methods (the necessary ones) of the GMSMapViewDelegate are called, but the method didLongPressAtCoordinate is not called at all. I tried with didTapOnCoordinate and this also works but the didLongPressAtCoordinate not.

Did/do someone else had/have the same problem?